# Spinner cannot load an integer array?

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have an application, which has a Spinner that I want populated with some numbers (4,8,12,16).  I created an integer-array object in strings.xml with the items mentioned above,  set the entries of the Spinner to the integer-array, and when I run the app I get:

```
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:198)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7965)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2989)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7965)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2989)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7965)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7965)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2989)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7965)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:763)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1632)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-19 23:38:48.016: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10193):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As soon as I changed the array to a string-array, this works fine.  Is this normal?  I realize that I can (and will) just convert the string array values to an int, but it seems weird that I have to.

Thanks!

EDIT: Anyone?  Anything?

Comment: hmm, I thought that this would be a simple yes/no answer.

Comment: Is there any way that you can post some code. It will be easier to look at code rather than a generic NPE.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**What you are attempting to do is not supported.**

You likely have some code that looks like this:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.numbers, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Which is of course calling the following:

```
/**
 * Creates a new ArrayAdapter from external resources. The content of the array
 * is obtained through {@link android.content.res.Resources#getTextArray(int)}.
 *
 * @param context The application's environment.
 * @param textArrayResId The identifier of the array to use as the data source.
 * @param textViewResId The identifier of the layout used to create views.
 *
 * @return An ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>.
 */
public static ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> createFromResource(Context context,
        int textArrayResId, int textViewResId) {
    CharSequence[] strings = context.getResources().getTextArray(textArrayResId);
    return new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(context, textViewResId, strings);
}
```

The call to `getTextArray` returns an array with null objects rather than the string representation of the values in your integer array.  Digging deeper reveals the source of the problem is in a method of `AssetManager`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the text array associated with a particular resource
 * identifier.
 * @param id Resource id of the string array
 */
/*package*/ final CharSequence[] getResourceTextArray(final int id) {
    int[] rawInfoArray = getArrayStringInfo(id);
    int rawInfoArrayLen = rawInfoArray.length;
    final int infoArrayLen = rawInfoArrayLen / 2;
    int block;
    int index;
    CharSequence[] retArray = new CharSequence[infoArrayLen];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < rawInfoArrayLen; i = i + 2, j++) {
        block = rawInfoArray[i];
        index = rawInfoArray[i + 1];
        retArray[j] = index >= 0 ? mStringBlocks[block].get(index) : null;
    }
    return retArray;
}
```

This code assumes you have provided the resource id of an array of strings and thus it is unable to properly extract out values from your array of integers.

Comment: I appreciated the explanation as well.  I had a feeling it was unsupported, but I couldn't really find a reason why - now I have one.

Comment: Thanks for the elucidation.  I had the same problem when assigning  an integer array to a spinner in a layout file.

Answer (score 2):

To overcome this problem, simply put quotes around your int values

```
<array name="spinner_value">
    <item>"18"</item>
    <item>"8"</item>
</array>
```