# Setting the drop down list of a spinner with an int[] array

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

In my app I have a spinner in which the user selects a number. I have tried the following, and it works, but it requires a `string-array` in the values.XML file,which is impractical for me as I have several of these with differing ranges (between 80-100 items long).

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.number_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This works, but it requires this;

```
<string-array name="number_array">
<item>1</item>
.....
</string-array>
```

So I have created an int array instead -

```
    int [] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

But creating an array adapter like this doesn't work

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        intArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Is there any way to do this or am I stuck with a lot of long numerical `string-arrays` in my values.xml file?

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2879680/603744

Comment: you can also create a String array from your int array. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619850/converting-an-int-array-to-a-string-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code

```
  String[] array = {"1", "2","3", "4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
  ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
  (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
```

instead of

```
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
  intArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved my problem thanks to the links provided in the comments under that question by first converting my `int[]` array to a string array using this link

- [Converting an int array to a String array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619850/converting-an-int-array-to-a-string-array)

Then I used the answers in this link to set the values of the spinner to a string array

- [Android: Create spinner programmatically from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array)