# Sort xml String Array for Spinners

Tags: android, arrays, sorting, android-spinner

Using [String Array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) am populating Spinner like this

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lang);
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
           R.array.lang_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but my `R.array.lang_array` is not sorted and `createFromResource` requires `TextArrayResId` when i sort using

```
String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lang_array);
Arrays.sort(list);
```

But now i have to convert String array to TextArrayResId which i am failed to convert also is there any alternate solution for sorting `R.array.Lang_array`
 saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671657/spinner-cannot-load-an-integer-array) but was not able to implement
Please help
Regards

Comment: cannot you use: `new  ArrayAdapter(...)`?

Comment: You can directly set xml array as input to spinner like "android:entries="@array/array_name"" and declare this list in xml in sorted order if its small

Comment: i know i need sort it first @Anil

Comment: so use `new ArrayAdapter(...)`

Comment: @pskink i am trying to implement you suggestion

Comment: @pskink  `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_setting, list), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);` this giving me compile time error what i am doing wrong?

Comment: delete it and write again not using copy paste

Comment: if you can help little bit i am noob here

Comment: thanks @pskink without copy paste the task was much easy thanks

Comment: no problem, sometimes things that should help (^C^V) dont help much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this**

```
List<String> lines= Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lang_array));
Collections.sort(lines);
```

Comment: this is `java.util.Arrays` for array sorting

Comment: i think i have done sorting now i have to implement it to `Spinner`

Comment: Good .. @phpdroid